# register_shutdown_function and ignore_user_abort are not working in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, openwrt

I have a simple php page that streams ping results. It works fine but when the user closes the connection, the ping command keeps running in the background. I used both `ignore_user_abort()` and `register_shutdown_function()`, but none worked. 
It is running on OpenWRT with uhttpd.
this is my code in a class-based approach.

```
class process
{
    private $proc;
    private $pid;
    private $descriptorspec;

    function start($cmd)
    {
        $cwd = '/tmp';
        $this->proc = proc_open($cmd, $this->descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);
        $this->pid = proc_get_status($this->proc)['pid'];
        session_write_close();
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
        ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);

        while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
            echo ">" . fread($pipes[1], 4096);
            flush();
            ob_flush();
            while (ob_get_level()) {
                ob_end_clean();
            }
            if (connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL) {
                shell_exec("killall ping &");
                break;
            }
        }
        pclose($this->proc);
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, "onShutdown"));
        $this->descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
            1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
            2 => array("file", "/tmp/app/proc.error.output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
        );
    }

    function onShutdown()
    {
        shell_exec("killall ping &");
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        shell_exec("killall ping");
//        posix_kill($this->pid, SIGKILL);
//        proc_terminate($this->proc);
//        pclose($this->proc);
    }
}
```

This is my function-based approach.

```
    global $proc, $pid;
    while (@ ob_end_flush()) ;

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("file", "/tmp/app/proc.error.output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
    );
    $cwd = '/tmp';
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);
    $pid = proc_get_status($proc)['pid'];
    session_write_close();
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    register_shutdown_function('on_shutdown');

    while (ob_get_level()){
        ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    //ob_start();
    while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
        echo fread($pipes[1], 4096);
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        if (connection_aborted() != 0) {
            posix_kill($pid, SIGKILL);
            pclose($proc);
        }
    }
    //ob_end_flush();
    pclose($proc);
```

Comment: Can't you start the process on the background by registering a init script in `OpenWRT`?

Comment: When the script can run until infinity `set_time_limit(0);`, at wich point should the `register_shutdown_function()` do its work? The script never stops.

Comment: @DarkBee I can but that is exactly the opposite of what I need. I want the process not to run in background, init scripts in OpenWrt are made for running in background.

Comment: @Foobar I know with `set_time_limit(0);` it should run infinity, but it doesn't and that is my problem. I assume that I am doing something wrong, What approach do you recommend to make sure that ping is not running in the background.

Comment: I dont really know how the complete system should work. But when you show all users the same ping data, may you can use an `WebSocket Stream`. Then the websocket server (PHP) will send the new ping data to the connected clients (Javascript). And if no client is connected, now ping check will be done.  Then you must not stream the `ping`command itself and it will never run in background. You call the ping command periodically and send the new data to all connected clients.  Check if that is a way to go for you. e.g. https://github.com/bloatless/php-websocket#timers

Answer (score -1):

Check phpinfo for the environment setup, set PATHs, if shell_exec is disabled, or FPM runs in a chroot.